# Issue adding an array record in nested document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on this since few hours but I am stuck on it. I am not getting the desired output. I am able to insert/update an array inside the collection but the design is not exactly what I wanted.

Desired output:

```
"app_mode_list" : [
        {
            "name" : "Office", 
            "_id" : "OFFICE"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Cash and Carry", 
            "_id" : "CASH_AND_CARRY"
        }
    ]
```

Output, what I am getting on the mongo chef (in the collection):

```
"app_mode_list" : {
        "1" : {
            "name" : "Office", 
            "_id" : "OFFICE"
        }, 
        "0" : {
            "name" : "Cash and Carry", 
            "_id" : "CASH_AND_CARRY"
        }
    }
```

Schema design:

```
var PortalSchema = new Schema({
        name:String,
        app_mode_list :[tokenRefSchema] 
    }, {
        collection:'portal',
        timestamps:{createdAt:'created_at', updatedAt:'updated_at'}
    }
);

var TokenRefSchema = Schema({
        _id:String, 
        name:String
    },
    {_id: false}
);
```

Controller:
I'm using an array name "app_mode_list" to push all the records in it.

```
    app_mode_list.push({"_id":$scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list._id,
"name":$scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list.name});
```

Then, I cast this array to my scope just before use hit the *save* button.

```
$scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list = app_mode_list;
```

Full Controller code:

```
    angular.module('rugCoPro')

.controller('PortalSettingsController', ['$scope', 'Session', '$location', 'ObjectUtils', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', 'JsonRest','$mdDialog','$mdToast', function($scope, session, $location, ObjectUtils, $http, $state, $stateParams, JsonRest,$mdDialog,$mdToast){


    if(!session.isAuthenticated()){
        session.logout();
    }

    $http.get("api/models/payroll_frequency").success(function(response, status, headers){
        $scope.payrollFrequencies = response;
    }); 
    $http.get("api/models/app_mode").success(function(response, status, headers){
        $scope.appModes = response;
    });   


    $scope.portalSettings = $stateParams.portal;
    console.log("portalSettings: --->> "+ JSON.stringify($scope.portalSettings, null, "    "));


    if(ObjectUtils.isObject($scope.portalSettings)){
        $scope.title = "Editing Settings";
         $scope.app_mode_list = $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list;
         console.log("1 $scope.app_mode_list : ", JSON.stringify($scope.app_mode_list, null, "   "));
         console.log(" 1 $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list : ", JSON.stringify( $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list, null, "   "));

    }

    $scope.cancel = function(){
        $state.go($stateParams.backState);
    };

    $scope.save = function(){
        if(ObjectUtils.isObject($scope.portalSettings)){
            var req;  

            $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list = ($scope.app_mode_list);

            console.log(" $scope.app_mode_list : ", JSON.stringify($scope.app_mode_list, null, "   "));
            console.log("  $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list : ", JSON.stringify( $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list, null, "   "));

            var sendableEntry = JsonRest.sanitize($scope.portalSettings, true);
            req = $http.put("api/portal/" + $scope.portalSettings._id, sendableEntry);

            req.success(function(response, status, headers){
                var user = session.getUser();
                if(ObjectUtils.isObject(response) && ObjectUtils.isObject(user)){
                    user.portal = response;
                    session.setUser(user);
                };
                $state.go($stateParams.backState);  
            });
        }

    };


    $scope.app_mode_list = [];

    // a list born with awesome features. 

    // yeah.. welcome aboard a new entry
    $scope.addToList = function(){
       // if(ObjectUtils.isObject($scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list)){
        if($scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list === undefined){
            var msg = "Please select a 'App Mode'!!"
                showSimpleToast(msg);
        }
        else{

            if(findIndexItem($scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list) == '-1'){
                $scope.app_mode_list.push(
                                    {
                                     "_id"  :   $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list._id,
                                     "name"  :   $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list.name
                                    }

                            );
                console.log("$scope.app_mode_list : " + JSON.stringify($scope.app_mode_list, null, "   "));

            }
            else{
                var msg = "'" + $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list.name + "' is already in the list."
                showSimpleToast(msg);
            }
        }
    };

    // sarifice what make you unforgettable. bye bye you old entry!! 
    $scope.deleteFromList = function(item, event){
        var confirmDialog = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title('Are you sure?')
            .textContent('Do you want to delete <' + item.name + ">?")
            .ariaLabel('Confirm Delete Dialog')
            .ok('Yes')
            .cancel('No')
            .targetEvent(event);

        $mdDialog.show( confirmDialog )
            .then(function(){
                $scope.app_mode_list.splice(findIndexItem(item.name),1);
            });
    };

    // okay scout! lets find your place. :)
    var findIndexItem= function(argu){
        // no need to check the hold         
            var i = null;
            for (i = 0; $scope.app_mode_list.length > i; i += 1) {
                if ($scope.app_mode_list[i].name == argu.name) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
    }

    //i am hungrey, where is my toast.
    var showSimpleToast = function(msg) {

        $mdToast.show(
          $mdToast.simple()
            .textContent(msg)
            .hideDelay(3000)
            .position('bottom right')
        );
    };

}]);
```

console output:
[image]

Comment: i assumed you are using `mongo` and share mongo schema.Problem here is in your schema

Comment: Your code looks fine where you are getting that json output, put relevant code of controller

Comment: @ArifKhan I am using mongo chef to view this collection. I get this output after saved this record.

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad Yes, I am using mongoDB and mongoose to run the queries. Could you be more specific about what problem you are talking about??

Comment: Can you provide full controller code?

Comment: @jatinderbhola $scope.app_mode_list = $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list; // check this line of code. Print the $scope.portalSettings.app_mode_list; array

Comment: attached output @ti2005

Comment: @jatinderbhola Now you are getting the correct output right? i.e, initial everything working fine right?

Comment: I was getting the correct output on console but when it saves in the collection, it looks like

`{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("******5b6485f330603f"),  
    "name" : "Trp", 
    "app_mode_list" : {
        "1" : {
            "name" : "Office", 
            "_id" : "OFFICE"
        }, 
        "0" : {
            "name" : "Cash and Carry", 
            "_id" : "CASH_AND_CARRY"
        }
    }
}` @ti2005 please check the "output what I am getting" heading in the questuon.

Comment: @jatinderbhola req = $http.put("api/portal/" + $scope.portalSettings._id, sendableEntry); just print the 'sendableEntry' before sending in browser console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124584/discussion-between-ti2005-and-jatinder-bhola).